# How do I increase indentation in visual studio / resharper format with 4 or more spaces

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper, indentation, code-formatting

When I do automatic code formatting with visual studio format, or resharper format, it uses 2 spaces for indentation.

I want to make it 4 or even 6 spaces, where is the setting to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is done on a language-by-language basis.

In the Tools menu, select Options...

In the dialog that appears, expand the Text Editor tree item, the language you are interested in, and select the Tabs pane.

In the Tabs pane, change the Indent size field.

[image]